# jquery click not removing the html from the DOM on firefox

Tags: jquery

I wanted to remove the html from the dom after clicking which is working fine on the google chrome but not on the firefox.

i have written the code which is working fine with google chrome but it is not working on the firefox i have to click 4-5 times to remove the unread_count span from the dom in firefox.

```
<li class="user_id list-item <?php if (isset($_GET['reciver_id']) && $_GET['reciver_id'] == $t->reciver_id) {
                                            echo "selected";
                                        } ?> "
                                            data-user-id="{{$t->reciver_id}}"
                                            data-conversation-id="{{$t->id}}" >

                                            <span class="badge badge-success float-right unread_count" ><?php  if($unread >0 ){echo  $unread;}  ?></span>
                                        @if(!empty($user->profile_avatar))
                                                <div class="user-img">
                                                    <img src="{{ URL::asset('public') }}/uploads/avatars/{{$user->profile_avatar}}" id="" alt="test image" class="img-thumbnail"/>
                                                    <!-- <span class="badge badge-success float-right unread_count"><?php  //if($unread >0 ){echo  $unread;}  ?></span> -->
                                                </div>
                                            @else
                                                <div class="user-img">
                                                    <img src="{{ URL::asset('public') }}/uploads/avatars/default_profile.png" id="" alt="test image" class="img-thumbnail"/>
                                                    <!-- <span class="badge badge-success float-right unread_count"><?php  //f($unread >0 ){echo  $unread;}  ?></span> -->
                                                 </div>
                                            @endif

                                            <h5>{{ \App\User::find($t->reciver_id)->first_name}} {{ \App\User::find($t->reciver_id)->last_name}}</h5>

                                            <div class="clear"></div>
                                        </li>


$(".user_id").click( function (e) {

                var _this = $(this);


scrollToBottom();
                //e.preventDefault();
                var conversation_id = $(this).data('conversation-id');
                var reciver_id = $(this).data('user_id');

                console.log($(this).data('user-id'));
                $(this).css('background', '#e2e2e2');

                 $(".selected").find('span#remove_count').detach();

                //   $(this).next('span#remove_count').css({"display": "none"});


                 $(".selected").find('span.unread_count').remove();

                //  $(".selected").find("span.unread_count").css({"display": "none"});  

                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: '<?php echo url("/mark-as-read"); ?>',
                    data: {"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}", "conversation_id": conversation_id,"reciver_id":reciver_id},
                    success: function (response) {

                        if (response) {    



                        }

                    }
                });

                // throw  new Error("test");


                window.location.href = 'chat?reciver_id' + '=' + $(this).data('user-id') + '&conversation_id=' + conversation_id;
setInterval(function() {

                    console.log("funtion is triggering");
    $('.selected').trigger('click');
}, 3000);
                //alert(conversation_id);

                //$("#user_to_chat_with").html($(this).data('user-id'));
                // console.log(window.location.href)

            });

            var reciver_id = getUrlParameter('reciver_id');
            var conversation_id = getUrlParameter('conversation_id');


            if (reciver_id != undefined && conversation_id != undefined) {
                getUserMessages(reciver_id, conversation_id);
            //  $("#chat_message").animate({scrollTop: $(document).height()}, 5000);

             scrollToBottom();
                //  $("#chat_message").animate({ scrollTop: $('#chat_message').prop("scrollHeight")}, 1000);
            }


            function getUserMessages(reciver_id, conversation_id) {

                setInterval(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "post",
                        url: '<?php echo url('/get-user-messages/'); ?>',
                        data: {
                            "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                            "reciver_id": reciver_id,
                            "conversation_id": conversation_id
                        },
                        // dataType: 'json',

                        success: function (response) {

                            //console.log(response);

                    //   $("#chat_message").animate({ scrollTop: $('#chat_message').prop("scrollHeight")}, 1000);




                            $("#chat_message").html(response);
                            //  $("#chat_message").animate({scrollTop: $(document).height()}, 5000);
                            scrollToBottom();


                        }
                    });

                }, 1500);

            }


        });
```

i wanted to remove the span with the class unread_count from the dom which is working fine in the google chrome but when i check the same on the firefox i need to click 4-5 times to remove it from the dom where i was expecting the element should be removed on the single click on the firefox

Comment: Can you please add the relevant HTML part and clean a little the Javascript so we have only the relavant part too?

Comment: Please check firefox console if there is any broken code.

Comment: @Kaddath i have edited the code please check.

Comment: @YasserMas there is no error in the console.